# Teamcity build on every git commit vs build on pull request

Tags: git, teamcity

We are setting up teamcity for our project which uses git. We have this debate on if we should trigger a build on every commit or on every pull request.

If i push a branch say A, and we have configured build on pull request on master then will the build be triggered on how the merged code will appear or it will just build the branch ?

Lets imagine that we have configures our teamcity to build every pull request

Now Lets say i have a branch master, developer A checksout a branch ftb_A. Creates a new test case and commits. Developer A code is not yet merged to master. Develope B creates a new branch ftb_B he also creates new test case. Now developer A pushes the branch and raises a pull request so build runs the test case added by develope A runs. Now pull request from developer A is merged and the newly created tesr case is available in master now.

Now developer B also pushes his branch, but he has not rebased his branch i.e. the test case which was added by developer A is not available in brach ftb_B. Now developer B raises a pull request. So build is triggered. Now my question is when the build is triggered for pull request raised by developer B will the test case added by developer A in master will run or not

Comment: Can you please update question description with exact requirement ?

Comment: Yes, it'll run. Git tracks changes in files and able to merge them correctly in your example. Even if dev B doesn't update her/his branch with dev A's code, s/he either can't merge her/his branch or both changes will work together according to have a conflict or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not indicated, I'm going to assume that you are using GitHub here.

In short: yes, the pull request from ftb_B will be updated any time changes are pushed to master. However, you must trigger your build on the **pull request branch**, not on ftb_B itself.

To explain: when a pull request from ftb_B is created, GitHub will generate you a new (hidden) branch that consists of the changes from ftb_B merged to the tip of master. This enables you to review the changes, run TeamCity builds against it and perform any other steps you might want before accepting the pull request. If the pull request from ftb_A is accepted **before** the creation of the pull request from ftb_B, these changes will naturally be included in the pull request branch. If the pull request from ftb_A is accepted **after** the creation of the pull request from ftb_B, GitHub will detect the change in the master branch and update the pull request branch for you. So you are good in either case.

The flow might look something like this:

1. ftb_A pull request created
2. ftb_A pull request branch created automatically by GitHub
3. ftb_B pull request created
4. ftb_B pull request branch created automatically by GitHub

   - This branch does **not** include changes from ftb_A at this point
5. ftb_A pull request accepted
6. master is updated
7. ftb_B pull request branch is updated automatically by GitHub

   - Now changes from ftb_A are reflected in the pull request branch

Check this out for more info:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/

Comment: the second scenario you discussed if pull request from ftb_A and ftb_B both are raised and ftb_A pull request is merged git will auto update ftb_B pull request. In that case will teamcity auto trigger a build on pull request from ftb_B ??

Comment: @AmbujJauhari: yes, it will. You have to configure a VCS trigger on your build in TeamCity, then it will detect the branch changes and trigger a build for you. If you don't want builds triggered on all commits, you can configure the trigger to only automatically build on commits to pull request branches using a branch filter. See the docs for more info: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-BranchFilter

Comment: Anyone knows a solution for this outside of Github? E.g on bitbucket?